# How to add an operation in azure APIM policy that dowloads file document stored in sharepoint without using Azure functions?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have a requirement to create operation in azure API Management that gives the possibility to download a file (For information files are stored in sharepoint document entity), is there a way to do so without working with Azure functions and just using APIM policy ?

thank you in advance for any information provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the share point exposes an HTTP endpoint you can import those apis in API Management and you can do a REST call to SharePoint and get the file.

Please refer for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-and-publish